# AWS CLI S3 list with a default endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using the following command on some ec2 instances in order to get some configuration files from an s3 bucket. The ec2 has an instance role attached with s3 full permissions:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/file ./ --region eu-west-1
```

This work as expected on some instances provided by me with a default ami, but one some existing instances in the same region and AZ with the same instance role i'm facing the following error:

```
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://bucket-name.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&delimiter=2%F&prefix=&encoding-type=url"
failed to run commands: exit status 255
```

My question is why the S3Uris is not prefixed with s3:// and returns the error with url string https:// ? it's clear that this aws cli version tries to reach s3 through https not by s3:// endpoint provided by me in the command. Is there anyway to overwrite this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why the S3Uris is not prefixed with s3:// and returns
> the error with url string https:// ?

Behind the scenes `aws cli` call the AWS services using `HTTPS` so that why is why on timeout you see `https://bucket-name.eu-west-1...`  timeout instead of `s3://` .

> By default, the AWS CLI sends requests to AWS services by using HTTPS on TCP port 443. To use the AWS CLI successfully, you must be able to make outbound connections on TCP port 443.

[aws-cli-chap-using](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-using.html)

The timeout on some instance might be because they are in private subnet without [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html).

you can simply verify this by doing `ping google.com` if it not responding then the instance in the private subnet without NAT or has no outbound allowed traffic.

Comment: Make sense, thanks, it was a route conf at the subnet level.